# where to find logic for Livewire table with parameters

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-livewire, laravel-livewire-wiremodel

I want to change query of the livewire table which displaying profiles on my admin panel, but don't know where i can find back-end Mysql query for modification. here is code for my live wire table .

```
 <div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="table-responsive mt-2">
        <livewire:table.profile :params="['filter' => $this->filter]"/>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I am facing difficulty to trace out where the database query for the table is written in LiveWire.

> i need the exact file where i can find my MYSQL/Eloquent query.please guide me where this table code exist in my project **livewire:table.profile**

I checked my whole project by could't not trace out the exact query location

Comment: did you check inside app/Http/Livewire/table/Profile.php

Comment: livewire:table.profile -> table is the folder and profile is the file inside the folder table

Comment: excatly it's here "app/Http/Livewire/table/Profile.php". Thank you @haruk1515